# Array Not Deleting Duplicates

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

I am trying to make it to where an array loads items into a table view from core data. Some of the values are duplicates though. So, within the array that I am using to fetch the data, I am trying to tell the array to remove any duplicates and then display it in the table view. But for some reason it is not removing the duplicates. Here is the code:

**UPDATED**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *weightEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tracking" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:weightEntity];
    result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];

    NSMutableArray *cleaningArray= [NSMutableArray new];
    NSSet *duplicatesRemover = [NSSet setWithArray:result];
    [duplicatesRemover enumerateObjectsUsingBlock: ^(id obj, BOOL* stop)
    {
        if(![cleaningArray containsObject: obj])
        {
            [cleaningArray addObject: obj];
        }
    }];

    cleanArray = [cleaningArray copy];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    mainCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (mainCell == nil) {
        mainCell = [[dictionaryTableCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    Entity *person = [cleanArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    mainCell.nameLabel.text = person.date;

    return mainCell;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [cleanArray objectAtIndex:0]);
    return   cleanArray.count;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are they _really_ duplicates, i.e. pointers to same piece of memory, or are they different objects with 'same' content?

Comment: Different objects with the same content. Any suggestions @HeWas

Comment: What is the content type? NSString? NSNumber? Custom object?

Comment: @HeWas Its just an NSString loaded from Core Data being put into an NSArray.

Comment: Did yuo try trimming the NSStrings? You could try [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] before putting them inside Core Data at the first place.

Comment: @Ravi No I have not. But dont know how

Comment: But see the way it is set up is that I need the values to be saved in Core data but not to be displayed as duplicates in the array. @Ravi

Comment: There should be a place in your program where the NSStrings are dumped inside Core Data, right? That's where you trim them.

Comment: no duplicated item array? that's NSOrderedSet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-containsObject compares strings  (as in [string1 isEqual:string2]) so you could do this

```
NSArray* result = @[@"test",@"string",@"test",@"line"];
    NSMutableArray* cleanArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


   for (id object in result) {
        if (![cleanArray containsObject:object])
            [cleanArray addObject:object];
    }

NSLog (@"cleanArray %@",cleanArray);
```

log:

```
cleanArray (
    test,
    string,
    line
)
```

*update*
@dreamlax and I been chatting with @Zack. It seems the NSSet / isEqual issue was a red herring. The "result" array does not contain NSStrings, it contains fetch requests for Core Data, each of which are of course unique, even if the data returned isn't. This array is tightly coupled with the table view, which executes those fetch requests ... on request.

So what Zack needed to do was to decouple Core Data from his Table View, pre-fetch the strings he wants to compare for uniqueness, and feed that uniqued array to the Table View. NSSet works fine for obtaining a unique set of results.

```
fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init]; 
NSEntityDescription *weightEntity = 
        [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" 
                                 inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; 
[fetchRequest setEntity:weightEntity]; 
result = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                      error:nil]; 
NSMutableSet *dateSet = [NSMutableSet alloc] init]; 

for (id object in result) { 
    Entity *person = object; 
    NSString* dateString = person.date; 
    [dateSet addObject:dateString]; 
} 

self.dateArray = [dateSet allObjects];
```

Then in his tableView:

mainCell.nameLabel.text = [cleanArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: So then how would I populate cleanArray into the tableView? @HeWas

Comment: As you are doing now, but that wasn't your problem was it?

Comment: I didn't think it was but I tried what you are doing and it seems to still show the duplicates. So I dont know if it is the way I am pulling the info or what.

Comment: My method works, i've tested it (thats the real log output). Are you sure these are duplicates? Maybe you should post some logs.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22491/discussion-between-zack-and-he-was)

Answer (score 1):

With credits to dreamlax, It's a matter of overriding the isEqual: method, that's why `NSSet` doesn't remove your duplicate objects.

In your entity, override the isEqual method and return true if all the fields are equal, for example:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)anObject
{
    return self.attribute_1 == anObject,attribute_1 && ... && self.attribute_N== anObject.attribute_N; // Primitive types comparison in this example
}
```

Comment: Remember to override `hash` also. The recommended procedure is to override both if you want your object to play nicely in Foundation collections. When I'm feeling lazy, I sometimes return the hash of the most unique property of an object, but if you have a large collection of objects it would be better to devise a good hash.